# StackView: Overriding custom UIview intrinsicContent size produces very unexpected outcomes

Tags: swift, uiview, uistackview, intrinsic-content-size

After struggling with programmatic dynamic UI elements for the last few weeks I decided I would give UIstackView a try. 
I want custom UIView classes to occupy the stackview with different heights based upon user Input I would remove, add views on the fly.

I found out that stackViews base their 'cell' height upon the UI element's intrinsic content size. However, UIViews do not have one. I searched far and wide and found out that I need to override the View's intrisicContentsize function with one where I can explicitly set the width and height. 
However results are very unpredictable and I'm sure there is some little thing that I just do not know dat causes this weird behaviour. Since I'm new to the language and there are a LOT of gotcha's I'm just gonna paste the code here and hope you'll be able to spot what I'm doing wrong.

I've read the docs ofc, a lot of articles, they all point to that override funcion that does not seem to work form me.

This is my mainViewController class;

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

var bv = BackButtonView(frame: CGRect.zero, image: UIImage(named: "backArrow.png")!)

var redView : UIView  = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    return view
}();

var blueView : UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .blue
    return view
}();

let stack : UIStackView = {
    let stack = UIStackView();
    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    stack.axis = .vertical
    stack.distribution = .fillProportionally;
    stack.spacing = 8
    return stack;
}();

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let view = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    self.view = view
    self.view.addSubview(stack)
    createLayout()
    bv.intrinsicContentSize
    stack.addArrangedSubview(bv)
    print(bv.frame)
    print(bv.intrinsicContentSize)
    stack.layoutIfNeeded()
    stack.addArrangedSubview(redView)
    stack.addArrangedSubview(blueView)

}

private func setConstraints(view: UIView) -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
    return [
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
    ]
}

private func createLayout() {
    stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

}
}

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Now here's my custom UIClass that is giving me all this trouble:

```
import UIKit

public class BackButtonView : UIView {


public var size = CGSize(width: 10, height: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric)
override open var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
     return size
}

var button : UIButton;

public init(frame: CGRect, image: UIImage) {
    button = UIButton()
    super.init(frame : frame);
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    self.backgroundColor = .black
    self.addSubview(button)
    setupButton(image: image);
    print(button.intrinsicContentSize)
}
let backButtonTrailingPadding : CGFloat = -18

lazy var buttonConstraints = [
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
    button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
    button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: backButtonTrailingPadding),
]
private func setupButton(image: UIImage) {
    self.button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    self.button.setImage(image, for: .normal);
    self.button.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(buttonConstraints)

}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

struct anchors {
    var topAnchor = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var bottomAnchor = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var leadingAnchor = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var trailingAnchor = NSLayoutConstraint()
}
```

}

You can see that the specified width in the size proprrty gets ignored.
Under the above conditions., this is the output

[image: Al heights are equal here]
If I now change the my custom  UIClass's intrisiContentSize height to anyting else, this happens:

```
    public var size = CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: 10)
override open var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
     return size
}
```

result:  [image]

Please help me figure out what is and isn't going on

The final screen should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: what the design you need to accomplish

Comment: You have `stack.distribution = .fillProportionally;` in your stack view initialization, so what are you trying to achieve? Your stack view is fullscreen, one of the views should be 10px high, but the stack view is set up to distribute views proportionally. Maybe you should revise your layout hierarchy.

Comment: Thans for your answer. As I undersand it fill proportianlly allows the all the stackview's elements's intrinsicContent size to determine their respective stack cell's hieght is going to be. So one 'cell' can be 10 high and another can be 150 high.
What I'm trying to achieve is a stack view with different sized Views